# C# Replace and Remove text

Tags: c#, text, label

I am having a little problem with how to replace and remove the text from the label.

```
label1.Text = Users online: 1   browsing: 1 pages
```

I am using gethtmldocument to receive the `label1.Text` to be like above. My problem is I want the text to show only `Users Online: (number)`.

Now I am using `label1.Text.Remove(17)`. So I will get `Users online: 1` but the problem is when the users exceed the limit is `10` the text will count to `1` again not `10`.

And I am trying to use `label1.Text.replace("browsing: 1 pages","")`. But when user is online the `browsing: 1 pages` will change to `browsing: 2 pages` or others.

So my question is how can I receive the text only `Users online: ???`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using *regular expressions*: match the groups and represent them in the desired way:

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string source = "Users online: 479  browsing: 153 pages";

  // match.Groups["text"]   - "Users online: "
  // match.Groups["number"] - "479"
  var match = Regex.Match(source, "^(?<text>.*?)(?<number>[0-9]+)");

  // Users online: (479)
  label1.Text = $"{match.Groups["text"].Value.Trim()} ({match.Groups["number"].Value})";
```

**Edit:** Regular expression's pattern `^(?<text>.*?)(?<number>[0-9]+)` explanation:

```
 ^               - anchor: string's beginning
 (?<text> ...)   - group named "text" which contains
 .*?             - any characters, as few as possible
 (?<number> ...) - group named "number" which contains
 [0-9]+          - digits (char in [0..9] range); "+" - at least one
```

Comment: This code is working. But I have no idea about RegularExpressions. Can I ask that what "^(?<text>.*?)(?<number>[0-9]+)" means?

Comment: @Eddga: I've edited my answer (pattern explanation added); for further readding about regular expressions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions

Comment: @Eddga: check the pattern: `"^(?<text>.*?)(?<number>[0-9]+)"`: it seems that you've *skipped* the last `+`. If this doesn't help, please, provide your code

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use substring. Something like this:

```
 var x = //get the text

 var textToDisplay = x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf("b"); 

 Label1.Text = textToDisplay;
```

Comment: This answer is working too. But if they have more User Online b..... 10. its will remove all of b.... to last too. So I think this is too much specific. But Thanks for help.